# python selenium, how do I seperte functions with css selectors

Tags: css, python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to seperate my script into different functions (so its easier to re-use parts) however when I do so selenium seems to be unable to find css selectors.

Folder structure:

- Startup.py
- Webdriver folder

  - containing **init**.py
  - and login.py

startup.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webtesting import login

def browser(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton):
    print 'Starting up Firefox'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    print 'browsing to websiteadress'
    browser.get('websiteadress')
    login.loginsteps(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton)

usernamefield = '#login-username'
passwordfield = 'input.input-default:nth-child(5)'
loginbutton = '.button'

if __name__=='__main__':
    browser(usernamefield,passwordfield,loginbutton)
```

login.py

```
def loginsteps(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton):
    try:
        userlogin = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(usernamefield)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (userlogin)
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (usernamefield)
    try:
        userpass = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(passwordfield)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (userpass)
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (passwordfield)
    try:
        logincss = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(loginbutton)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (logincss)
        except:
            print 'Was not able to click login.'
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find login element.'
```

Now if I run this the browser starts up but I get the exceptions on the css selectors, so its unable to run the second function correctly in the browser session.

**prints in the terminal:**

- Starting up Firefox
- browsing to websiteadress
- Was not able to find an element <#login-username> with that name.
- Was not able to find an element 
  with that name.
- Was not able to find login element.

however when I test run it in one function it does work.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def browser(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton):
    print 'Starting up Firefox'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    print 'browsing to website'
    browser.get('webadress')
    #login.loginsteps(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton)
    try:
        userlogin = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(usernamefield)
        print 'found usernamefield element with that class name!'
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (usernamefield)
    try:
        userpass = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(passwordfield)
        print 'found userpass element with that class name!'
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (passwordfield)
    try:
        logincss = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(loginbutton)
        print 'found loginbutton element with that class name!'
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find login element.'

usernamefield = '#login-username'
passwordfield = 'input.input-default:nth-child(5)'
loginbutton = '.button'

if __name__=='__main__':
    startup.browser(usernamefield,passwordfield,loginbutton)
```

this returns does work however in this senario I'm unable to make seperate functions from parts of this script, turning it all into a big spaggeti mess.

- Starting up Firefox
- browsing to website
- found usernamefield element with that class name!
- found userpass element with that class name!
- found loginbutton element with that class name!

How do I make python selenium work with seperate functions?
as in the current setup I would have to copy past my script instead of being able to re-use code....

Answer (score 0):

resloved the issue:
The browser variable has to be returned and passed on into the next function

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webtesting import login

    def browser(usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton):
        print 'Starting up Firefox'
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        print 'browsing to websiteadress'
        browser.get('websiteadress')
        return browser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = browser()
    loginsteps(browser,usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton)
```

then pass the browser to the next script so its able to pickup the correct browser session.

```
def loginsteps(browser, usernamefield, passwordfield, loginbutton):
    try:
        userlogin = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(usernamefield)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (userlogin)
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (usernamefield)
    try:
        userpass = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(passwordfield)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (userpass)
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find an element <%s> with that name.' % (passwordfield)
    try:
        logincss = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(loginbutton)
        print 'found <%s> element with that class name!' % (logincss)
        except:
            print 'Was not able to click login.'
    except:
        print 'Was not able to find login element.'
```